# Error deploying an app to streamlit. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

Tags: flask, web-applications, streamlit

I have a flask web app (machine learning app) already deployed and running on Heroku at: https://hedeya-disaster-response-app.herokuapp.com/

When I tried to deploy it to Streamlit, I got the following error:

```
File "/app/disaster-response-pipeline-project/app/run.py", line 21, in <module>

    from app.classDefs import ItemSelector, tokenize, StartingVerbExtractor, MessageLengthExtractor # Heroku

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

Even when I tried to remove "app." from the above mentioned line, I got another error.

Here is a link to the github repository: https://github.com/hedeya1980/Disaster-Response-Pipeline-Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streamlit Community Cloud doesn't support deploying Flask apps. If you convert your app to a Streamlit app, the error should go away.